# Phonegap Plugins don't initialise

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

In my Phonegap project, I use a number of plugins. So far, including them worked instantly. Now I try to add File Opening abilities, but I have no luck in getting it to work. I use PhoneGap Build and the PhoneGap desktop developer application. I did not use the command line tools.

Here's why I think it should be working:

- config.XML contains:

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" source="npm" spec="~3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-fileopener" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" source="npm" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" />
```

- Barcode scanner and social sharing were included in the same way and did work straight away
- Cordova.js is included before the call to window.plugins.fileOpener.open() or cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open() is made
- PhoneGap Build does show in its logs that the plugins are installed without error. Also, the plugins directory does show that it downloaded the plugins from npm.

Here's what I tried to debug so far:

- Logging the `plugins` objects. They don't include any of the two file opening plugins. `window.plugins` contains insomnia and social sharing, `cordova.plugins` contains barcode scanner.
- Verifying device ready has been called; it has.
- When I call window.plugins.socialsharing.share() at the same point in the code, it does open the share dialog
- I have tested this via the PhoneGap app for Android, a built apk from PhoneGap Build, PhoneGap app for iPhone. All with the same result.

Comment: can you show some code including the device ready event?

Comment: I use it here: https://pastebin.com/SYKYxAhY It's a little tricky to get it in the context of device ready, because it's used in a function that's fired when the user clicks a button. On line 13, the alert does return true for deviceready.

Comment: i just wanted to make sure that you call the plugin after the `deviceready` event.

Comment: can you please try to console.log  `window.cordova.plugins.FileOpener`

Comment: It shows a blank line (in the PhoneGap desktop application), and `typeof window.cordova.plugins.FileOpener` returns `undefined`

Comment: why do you need both `cordova-plugin-file-opener2` and `cordova-plugin-file-opener`?

Comment: Do both File Opener plugins have the same underlying JavaScript files, with same names? That would be problematic.  Have you tried including just one at a time? Do that next.

Comment: I only need one of them, whichever one works. I checked it again: either just fileopener or file-opener2, but the result is the same as when including both of them which is the same as including neither of them.

Comment: I also verified that the respective plugin.XML has it's "clobbers" target set to `cordova.plugins.fileOpener2`, so that is indeed where the plugin should be accessible.